# C++ getting console error. I cant identify problem with my source code

Tags: c++

I have problem with my code and I dont know where exactly it is. I will try explain you how my program works.
For example some letters of the alphabet;

```
A = 1
B = 3
C = 7
D = 4
...
```

I defined these values to letters

And I will write in program phrase abcd and it will sum 1+3+7+4=`15` and it will check file `words.txt` also if it contains any phrase combined with letters which sum equals to `15`. If in `words.txt` would be for example not `abcd` but lets say `dbac` it will show you this phrase too because sum of this phrase also equals to `15`. I hope you understand.

This is source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <limits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

void print( string::size_type n, string const & s )
{
    if( n == string::npos ) {
        cout << "not found\n";
    } else {
        cout << "found: " << s.substr( n ) << '\n';
    }
}

map < char, int > make_pythagorean_map()
{
    return {
        { 'A', 1 },
        { 'a', 1 },
        { 'B', 2 },
        { 'b', 2 },
        { 'C', 3 },
        { 'c', 3 },
        { 'D', 4 },
        { 'd', 4 },
        { 'E', 5 },
        { 'e', 5 },
        { 'F', 6 },
        { 'f', 6 },
        { 'G', 7 },
        { 'g', 7 },
        { 'H', 8 },
        { 'h', 8 },
        { 'I', 9 },
        { 'i', 9 },
        { 'J', 1 },
        { 'j', 1 },
        { 'K', 2 },
        { 'k', 2 },
        { 'L', 3 },
        { 'l', 3 },
        { 'M', 4 },
        { 'm', 4 },
        { 'N', 5 },
        { 'n', 5 },
        { 'O', 6 },
        { 'o', 6 },
        { 'P', 7 },
        { 'p', 7 },
        { 'Q', 8 },
        { 'q', 8 },
        { 'R', 9 },
        { 'r', 9 },
        { 'S', 1 },
        { 's', 1 },
        { 'T', 2 },
        { 't', 2 },
        { 'U', 3 },
        { 'u', 3 },
        { 'V', 4 },
        { 'v', 4 },
        { 'W', 5 },
        { 'w', 5 },
        { 'X', 6 },
        { 'x', 6 },
        { 'Y', 7 },
        { 'y', 7 },
        { 'Z', 8 },
        { 'z', 8 }
    };
}

map < char, int > make_simpleeng_map()
{
    return {
        { 'A', 1 },
        { 'a', 1 },
        { 'B', 2 },
        { 'b', 2 },
        { 'C', 3 },
        { 'c', 3 },
        { 'D', 4 },
        { 'd', 4 },
        { 'E', 5 },
        { 'e', 5 },
        { 'F', 6 },
        { 'f', 6 },
        { 'G', 7 },
        { 'g', 7 },
        { 'H', 8 },
        { 'h', 8 },
        { 'I', 9 },
        { 'i', 9 },
        { 'J', 10 },
        { 'j', 10 },
        { 'K', 11 },
        { 'k', 11 },
        { 'L', 12 },
        { 'l', 12 },
        { 'M', 13 },
        { 'm', 13 },
        { 'N', 14 },
        { 'n', 14 },
        { 'O', 15 },
        { 'o', 15 },
        { 'P', 16 },
        { 'p', 16 },
        { 'Q', 17 },
        { 'q', 17 },
        { 'R', 18 },
        { 'r', 18 },
        { 'S', 19 },
        { 's', 19 },
        { 'T', 20 },
        { 't', 20 },
        { 'U', 21 },
        { 'u', 21 },
        { 'V', 22 },
        { 'v', 22 },
        { 'W', 23 },
        { 'w', 23 },
        { 'X', 24 },
        { 'x', 24 },
        { 'Y', 25 },
        { 'y', 25 },
        { 'Z', 26 },
        { 'z', 26 }
    };
}

map < char, int > make_gfive_map()
{
    return {
        { 'A', 7 },
        { 'a', 7 },
        { 'B', 8 },
        { 'b', 8 },
        { 'C', 1 },
        { 'c', 1 },
        { 'D', 2 },
        { 'd', 2 },
        { 'E', 3 },
        { 'e', 3 },
        { 'F', 4 },
        { 'f', 4 },
        { 'G', 5 },
        { 'g', 5 },
        { 'H', 6 },
        { 'h', 6 },
        { 'I', 7 },
        { 'i', 7 },
        { 'J', 8 },
        { 'j', 8 },
        { 'K', 9 },
        { 'k', 9 },
        { 'L', 1 },
        { 'l', 1 },
        { 'M', 2 },
        { 'm', 2 },
        { 'N', 3 },
        { 'n', 3 },
        { 'O', 4 },
        { 'o', 4 },
        { 'P', 5 },
        { 'p', 5 },
        { 'Q', 6 },
        { 'q', 6 },
        { 'R', 7 },
        { 'r', 7 },
        { 'S', 8 },
        { 's', 8 },
        { 'T', 9 },
        { 't', 9 },
        { 'U', 1 },
        { 'u', 1 },
        { 'V', 2 },
        { 'v', 2 },
        { 'W', 3 },
        { 'w', 3 },
        { 'X', 4 },
        { 'x', 4 },
        { 'Y', 5 },
        { 'y', 5 },
        { 'Z', 6 },
        { 'z', 6 }
    };
}

map < char, int > select_map( int choice )
{
    switch( choice )
    {
    case 1:
        {
            return make_pythagorean_map();
        }
    case 2:
        {
            return make_simpleeng_map();
        }
    case 3:
        {
            return make_gfive_map();
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int cho = 0, d, help;
    char o;
    string phrasetwo;

    while( 1 )
    {
        system( "cls" );
        cout << "You want to use: " << endl << "1) Pythagorean Gematria" << endl << "2) English/Simple Gematria" << endl << "3) Extra: " << endl << "Gematria with G = 7" << endl << endl;
        cin >> phrasetwo;
        istringstream asd( phrasetwo );

        if( !( asd >> d ) || asd >> o )
        {
            system( "cls" );
            cout << "You want to use: " << endl << "1) Pythagorean Gematria" << endl << "2) English/Simple Gematria" << endl << "3) Extra: " << endl << "Gematria with G = 7" << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cho = stoi( phrasetwo );
            if( cho <= 3 && cho >= 1 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    auto m = select_map( cho );

    string::size_type n;
    ifstream input( "words.txt" );
    ofstream output( "results.txt" );
    string str, phrase;
    int counter = 1, cnt = 0, choice = 0, chosennum = 0, asd = 0, f = 0, x;
    bool flag;
    char c;

    while( 1 )
    {
        system( "cls" );
        cout << "You want to check:" << '\n' << "1) Number" << '\n' << "2) Phrase" << endl;
        cin >> phrase;
        istringstream s( phrase );

        if( !( s >> x ) || s >> c )
        {
            system( "cls" );
            cout << "You want to check:" << '\n' << "1) Number" << '\n' << "2) Phrase" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            choice = stoi( phrase );
            if( choice <= 2 && choice >= 1 )
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    switch( choice )
    {
    case 1:
        {
            cout << "Which number do you want to check?: ";
            while( 1 )
            {
                cin >> phrase;
                istringstream s( phrase );

                if( !( s >> x ) || s >> c )
                {
                    cout << endl << "Which number do you want to check?: ";
                }
                else
                {
                    chosennum = stoi( phrase );
                    break;
                }
            }
            cout << endl << "All results found: " << endl;
            break;
        }

    case 2:
        {
            do
            {
                flag = false;
                cout << "Which phrase do you want to check?: ";

                cin.ignore( numeric_limits < streamsize >::max(), '\n' );
                getline( cin, phrase );

                for( int i = 0; i < phrase.length(); i++ )
                {
                    if( isdigit( phrase[ i ] ) )
                    {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
                cout << endl;
            } while( flag == true );

            for( char charr: phrase )
            {
                chosennum += m[ charr ];
            }
            cout << '\t' << phrase << " in gematria = " << chosennum << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    int tablica[4], b = 0, easy, H = 1, sum;
    string str2;
    string::size_type G;
    vector<pair< int, string > > Datas;

    while( getline( input, str ) )
    {
        sum = 0;
        n = str.find( ',' );
        G = n;

        if( n != string::npos )
        {
            do
            {
                tablica[ b ] = n;
                b++;
                n = str.find( ',', n + 1 );
            } while( n != string::npos );

            str2 = str.substr( tablica[ 3 ] + 1 );
            easy = stoi( str2 );
            str.resize( G );
            b = 0;
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++ )
        {
            if( ( ( int ) str[ i ] ) > 127 || ( ( int ) str[ i ] ) < 0 )
            {
                str.clear();
            }
        }

        for( char charr: str )
        {
            sum += m[ charr ];
        }

        if( sum == chosennum )
        {
            Datas.emplace_back(easy, str);
            help = sum;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    sort( Datas.begin(), Datas.end(), greater< pair< int, string > >() );

        for (const auto& e : Datas)
        {
            cout << "No[" << H << "]: " << e.second << '\t' << '\t' << '\t' << "Value In Gematria: " << help << '\t' << '\t' << '\t' << "Search Number: " << e.first <<'\n';
            output << "No[" << H << "]: " << e.second << '\t' << '\t' << '\t' << "Value In Gematria: " << help << '\t' << '\t' << '\t' << "Search Number: " << e.first <<'\n';
            H++;
        }

    cout << "\n\n You have found: " << ( counter - 1 ) << " phrases" << '\n';
    output << "\n\n You have found: " << ( counter - 1 ) << " phrases" << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

And program works properly. Everything is fine if my file `words.txt` looks in that way:

```
it wasnt humans, 1609, 1092, 182, 18
a worm wearing a human suite, 2787, 1674, 279, 18
a human full of worms, 1732, 1308, 218, 0
they call it symbiosis, 1436, 1470, 245, 6
angry abortions, 950, 1068, 178, 4
```

But when Im changing file `words.txt` to the file which contains almost 1,5mln lines I have error in console. Here is screenshot of error:
[Screenshot Of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D5Ty.png)

And I dont know what is going on. Looking forward for help. Thanks for answers.

Comment: You pass an invalid argument to the [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) function, which causes it to throw an [`std::invalid_argument`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) exception. Very likely there's an error in your input file.

Comment: I suggest you output every string that you pass to stoi, flush the output afterwards (by using `std::endl` for instance), this is very important. Then look at the last string output before the crash. That should give you some clue as to the problem. You can then work backwards from there. This is a good example of how you should approach finding a bug, write some code to help you track it down.

Comment: And for future question please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions, and how to create a [mcve] (with emphasis on the *minimal* part).

Comment: My input file with 1,5mln lines looks exactly the same like a short part which is shown above. Its only larger. How I can solve my problem?

Comment: "looks exactly the same". Famous last words.

Comment: Keep track of the lines you read (as well as the line-number), and catch the exception. When the exception is caught the print the line-number as well  the contents of the line.

Comment: Well fairly clearly one of the calls to stio() is throwing an exception. It's almost certainly the one in the line `easy = stoi( str2 );` because that's the only one that might behave differently when you change the file. Add a try/catch to catch the exception and log the line that caused the crash. It's probably a numeric value that's too large for a signed int, at a guess.

Comment: @CarlTheBest have you really examined all 1.5 million lines? It's virtually axiomatic that code which works well on small hand crafted data will fail when exposed to larger real world data.

Comment: @CarlTheBest Anyway add some debugging code to help you track down the problem. Several suggestions in the comments already.

Comment: I have changed ```int easy``` to ```long long int easy``` but it still doesnt work. Its possible @ChrisLong that value for ```easy = stoi (str 2 ); ``` is large because its number of how many times this exactly phrase was searched. How I can fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `catch` and see what is on `str2`:

```
try {
    easy = stoi( str2 );
} catch (const std::invalid_argument & ex) {
    std::cerr << "Error string: " << str2 << ", " << ex.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Ok I found problem. Thanks bro

Comment: Don't keep us in suspense - what was the problem? :-)